# Syncfusion Vuejs PivotTable Table

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, syncfusion

I am trying to use this Syncfusion Pivot table package in my project.
[Here is the link of package](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/pivotview/getting-started/?no-cache=1).

I just copied the code and paste it in my vue component.
Code I copied:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ejs-pivotview :dataSourceSettings="dataSourceSettings" :height="height"></ejs-pivotview>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from "vue";
  import { PivotViewPlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-pivotview";
  import { pivotData } from "./data.js";

  Vue.use(PivotViewPlugin);

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dataSourceSettings: {
          dataSource: pivotData,
          expandAll: false,
          columns: [
            { name: "Year", caption: "Production Year" },
            { name: "Quarter" }
          ],
          values: [
            { name: "Sold", caption: "Units Sold" },
            { name: "Amount", caption: "Sold Amount" }
          ],
          rows: [{ name: "Country" }, { name: "Products" }],
          filters: []
        },
        height: 350
      };
    }
  };
</script>

<style>
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-pivotview/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-lists/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-grids/styles/material.css";
  @import "../../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/styles/material.css";
</style>
```

But it's not giving the result as seen in demo:
Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Giving result:

[image: Result Image]

My Pivotdata in data.js. Here is the sample data:

```
 {
            "balance": 2430.87,
            "quantity": 11,
            "name": "Skinner Ward",
            "gender": "male",
            "company": "GROK",
            "state": "New Jercy"
        },
        {
            "balance": 3192.7,
            "quantity": 15,
            "name": "Gwen Dixon",
            "gender": "female",
            "company": "ICOLOGY",
            "state": "Vetaikan"
        },
        {
            "balance": 1663.84,
            "quantity": 14,
            "name": "Deena Gillespie",
            "gender": "female",
            "company": "OVERPLEX",
            "state": "New Jercy"
        }
```

Comment: console log whats in your pivotData. is it getting some data and correct data structure

Comment: Updated the question check the pivotData

Comment: i mean are you getting correct data in your component. Is your component file in the same directory as data.js file ?

Comment: Yes.. it's getting correct data

Comment: Try to add your example data directly to your component. Dont load it from file. e.g. `dataSource: [{"aaa":"bbb", "ccc":"ddd"},{"aaa":"eee","ccc":"fff"}],`

Comment: Nothing changed same result

Comment: remove columns, values, rows, filters lines

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned fields in report isn’t available in the bound data source. So, the component couldn’t be rendered. So, kindly use the available fields in the data source. 
Meanwhile, we have planned to include a tab in all the UG samples to showcase the data source bound in the report. It will be refreshed at the end of the month.

Meanwhile, we have prepared a sample for your reference with sample data.

Sample Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-d9z5o 
Online demo link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/demos/#/material/pivot-table/default.html